# How can we determine the Taylor polynomial?

Tags: calculus, analysis, taylor-expansion

I want to calculate the Taylor polynomial $T_{m;x_0}$ of order $m$ at $x_0=\left (\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}\right )$ for the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\cos (x_1+x_2)$.

We have the following:

\begin{align*}&f\left (\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}\right )=\cos \left (\frac{3\pi}{2}\right )=0\\ &\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_1}}=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_2}}=-\sin (x_1+x_2) \Rightarrow \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_1}}\left (\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}\right )=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_2}}\left (\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}\right )=1\\ &\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x_1}^2}=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_2}^2}=\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x_1x_2}}=-\cos (x_1+x_2) \Rightarrow \frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x_1}^2}\left (\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}\right )=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_2}^2}\left (\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}\right )=\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x_1x_2}}\left (\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}\right )=0\\& \frac{\partial^3{f}}{\partial{x_1}^3}=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_2}^3}=\sin (x_1+x_2) \Rightarrow \frac{\partial^3{f}}{\partial{x_1}^3}\left (\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}\right )=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_2}^3}\left (\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}\right )=-1 \\ & \frac{\partial^4{f}}{\partial{x_1}^4}=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_2}^4}=\cos (x_1+x_2)\Rightarrow \frac{\partial^4{f}}{\partial{x_1}^4}\left (\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}\right )=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_2}^4}\left (\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}\right )=0\end{align*} 
etc.

At the even derivatives are equal to $0$ and the odd ones are $1$ or $-1$.

How can we use that fact to determine the Taylor polynomial of order $m$?

The general formula is $$T_{m;x_0}=\sum_{k\leq m}\frac{D^kf(x_0)\cdot (x-a_0)^k}{k!}$$

Comment: What does $f(x)=\cos(x_1+x_2)$ mean?

Comment: $x$ is $(x_1, x_2)$. So we have the function$f(x_1, x_2)=\cos (x_1+x_2)$. @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: You need to also calculate $D^{x_1,x_2}f$ for second order, and for third order all the combination there and so on. Afterwards use that to calculate $\sum_{|\alpha|=k}D^{\alpha}f/\alpha!$ and finish it with adding the results from $k\le m$

Comment: But do we have to find a general pattern, or till which order do we have to calculate the derivatives? @Holo

Comment: I did not check that but if there is there is possibility that it will require more than one summation(you can see that as $k$ increase there are more terms in $\sum_{|\alpha|=k}$)

Comment: I got stuck right now... So, do I have to write just the first two or three terms of the sum or how can we determine the Taylor polynomial of order m ? @Holo

Comment: First notice that if $|\alpha|=|\beta|$ we can say about $D^\alpha f,D^\beta f$ that...? Afterwards it depends on the way the question was asked, unless specific otherwise I personally would just write the general form of 2 variables Taylor series (specifically 2 variables) and then add what I know about $D^\alpha f$

Answer (score 1):

different trick: Use $\cos(x+y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$ and $\cos(\pi/2)=\sin(\pi)=0$

Comment: But they are constant when we evaluate the derivatives at the point $x_0$. So, the higher derivatives don't vanish, do they?

Comment: How do we use this trick? I got stuck right now...

Comment: [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(x%2By) you can see the resulting series. note for the partial wrto x,y derivatives you can pull out the function only depending on the other variable, that reduces computation.

Comment: I don't really see how this help us. Could you explain it further to me?